# Pandas Merge on 2 common columns: Keep all of Left, Keep 2 columns from Right when it exists in the Left

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have 2 DataFrames.

The first includes the ID I want to keep plus details. One of those details is the address of an event. (159880 rows)

Th second DataFrame has the lat & lon of addresses in the first DataFrame (plus more). (121769)

This should be a many-to-one relationship as there are multiple events at the same address. As an output what I want is the first DataFrame with the lat & lon columns added. I can do this with `apply` and a simple search in the latlon DataFrame. However, that is very slow - tens of minutes slow. Therefore, I decided to try pandas.merge.

It seems to me that this should work:

```
combo = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_on=['col1', 'col2'], 
                 right_on=['col1_2', 'col2_2'], indicator='indicator_column')
```

This merge results in a DataFrame which has 726789 rows. The indicator column shows plenty of rows that are in 1 or the other DataFrame. They should all be from both or left_only. (There are some misspellings of the addresses so I expect some addresses won't match.)

I've tried several variations of inner, outer, and left merges. None result in a DataFrame with fewer than 500k rows.

Hours of googling have not helped. Likely because I'm not asking the question in the correct way. Nor have the sections of the Pandas docs on Join, Concat, and Merge that I've been reading.

Comment: Not sure you can expect much more help here without any indication of your data or how you want it to look like...

Comment: You are merge by address, but why there are two keys `col` and `col2` to merge.

Comment: you must have duplicate values, you could try and just drop all the duplicate rows...